# Count statement one to many relationship with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a count statement for a database. Each book can be in multiple categories (eg; horror and fiction), so I tried the statement below, but I just get 0 when I try to get the second category. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM book
Inner JOIN bookscategories ON book.bookid = bookscategories.bookid
WHERE bookscategories.categoryid = 3 AND bookscategories.categoryid = 4
```

Comment: `bookscategories.categoryid` cannot be equal to 3 and 4 in the same time ;-) Btw, question is not clear, try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `categoryid` can't be set to both 3 and 4 at the same time, which is what you're testing for when you use [`AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and). You'll probably need to use [`OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) instead, or alternatively you could use an [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause:

```
WHERE bookcategories.categoryid = 3 OR bookcategories.categoryid = 4
```

... or ...

```
WHERE bookcategories.categoryid IN (3, 4)
```

Comment: If it is what OP wanted - it could be also a good idea to move the condition to `ON` part

Answer (score 2):

This sql is assuming that you want to find the number of books that are in both category 3 and category 4. The other answers do an in cat 3 or cat 4

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM book 
Inner JOIN bookscategories bc ON b.bookid = bc.bookid
Inner JOIN bookscategories bc2 ON book.bookid = bc2.bookid
WHERE bc.categoryid = 3 AND bc2.categoryid = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that SQL works with the cartesian products of tables.

In your query, you'll have

```
book1   book1cat1
book1   book1cat2
```

You are asking that, for each record, book1cat1 is both 3 AND 4. It is impossible as it can only be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count for each category:

```
SELECT bookscategories.categoryid, count(book.bookid) as count
  FROM book
 Inner JOIN bookscategories ON book.bookid = bookscategories.bookid
                           AND bookscategories.categoryid in (3, 4)
 GROUP BY bookscategories.categoryid
```